# How to check if address points to data/code segment in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I would like to be able to tell apart strings that are constants from strings residing on heap. Is there a way to do that having just the address of a string? I am working on Linux x86_64.

Comment: Constant strings might be in the code/text section too.  Do you have access to your object file/executable?

Comment: Is there something specific you are trying to accomplish with this as there might be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Check if the address is on the heap. Anyway, why do you want to know this?

Comment: I want to count references to dynamically allocated strings. I was thinking about putting counter at the beginning of each string, but the problem are constants.

Comment: Can't you just declare them properly?  const char* foo = "bar";  No reason to prolong that ancient C flaw.

Comment: I am writing a simple compiler and this is what I wanted to do for garbage collecting, so it should work in assembly.

Comment: On linux you can consult `/proc/self/maps` to see where the heap is.